# Yii2 behaviors verbs actions HTTP Methods: post and get

Tags: yii2

Sometimes, not often, error message appears: "method not allowed yii2 this url can only handle...: POST

Such a code I found in the function behaviors:

```
'verbs' => [
'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
'actions' => [
'delete' => ['post']
```

Can it occurs this error message and why this error occurs sometimes(not often)?

ADDitional
Really, I apologize that forget to indicate that all it used by iframe(page open in an iframe window and apply to yii2 through a url and after the delete action was completed - was redirected back), may be a user is logged out, but doest understand it.

And the controller postController receive as post as get method: delete url as GET, _csrf   as POST

Comment: the above rule means it allows only post to access the `delete` action so a normal navigation without formsubmit wont be allowed on this action

Answer (score 0):

1. Only allow **delete** action via Post. ($_POST). For more security

   Example to access via the `get` and `post` method: Not recommended for `Delete` action.

   ```
       'verbs' => [
           'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
           'actions' => [
               'delete' => ['post','get'],
           ],
       ],
   ```

---

## Update:

Not always error #405 and may be #403 and ...

2. **Cookies and session expired**

   When you open several browser tabs(or windows) on your site and your session expires. You login through a window (or with another user). In this case the exception is thrown by clicking on the `logut` in other open tabs and windows(browser).

> This is because CSRF protection works only for unsafe request methods such  PUT, POST or DELETE. That's why in order to stay safe your application should never ever use GET requests to change application state.

3. If a logout by tag `<a>` or `url` in **nav** is set as follows:

   `'data-method' => 'post'`

Modify and try using form and ...

**example:**

```
        Html::beginForm(['.../logout'], 'post')
        . Html::submitButton(
            'Logout (' . Yii::$app->user->identity->username . ')',
            ['class' => 'btn btn-link']
        )
        . Html::endForm()
```

Comment: May be it`s the reason, but it`s strange that it works sometimes, and sometimes not....

Comment: Really, I apologize that forget to indicate that all it used by iframe(page open in an iframe window and apply to yii2 through a url and after the delete action was completed - was redirected back), may be a user is logged out, but doest understand it...

Comment: PostController receive as post as get data: action as GET and _csrf  as POST

Comment: ok, CSRF protection works only for unsafe request methods such  PUT, POST or DELETE.